# could not convert string to float: '\x00' when using a text file

Tags: python, numpy

this is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import stats

pixel,gray = np.loadtxt('vert1.txt',skiprows=3,unpack=True,delimiter=',')
gauss = stats.norm.pdf(pixel, 140, 15)
gauss=gauss*180060+770

def fermi(x,b,A,c,d):
    return A + b/(np.exp((x-c)/d)+1)

popt,pcov = curve_fit(fermi,pixel,gray,p0=[1,1,1,2])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(pixel,fermi(pixel,*popt),'r-',label='Fermi function')
plt.plot(pixel,gray,label='Experimental data')
plt.plot(pixel,gauss,color='tab:purple',label='Gaussian function')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Pixels')
plt.ylabel('Intensity, a.u.')
plt.title('Vertical distribution')
print('vertical ',popt)
#plt.savefig('knife edge vertical.svg', format='svg', dpi=1200)

pixel,gray_1 = np.loadtxt('horiz1.txt',skiprows=3,unpack=True,delimiter=',')

popt,pcov = curve_fit(fermi,pixel,gray_1,p0=[1,1,1,2])

gauss1 = stats.norm.pdf(pixel, 140, 23) #the third value is the FWHM
gauss1=gauss1*145600+970 #adjust the height of the Gaussian

plt.figure()
plt.plot(pixel,fermi(pixel,*popt),'r-',label='Fermi function')
plt.plot(pixel,gray_1,label='Experimental data')
plt.plot(pixel,gauss1,color='tab:purple',label='Gaussian function')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Pixels')
plt.ylabel('Intensity, a.u.')
plt.title('Horizontal distribution')
print('horizontal ',popt)
#plt.savefig('knife edge horiz.svg', format='svg', dpi=1200)
```

then my error : ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\x00'

My text file is a file like this :

```
1,3676.545
2,3986.354
3,4069.556
```

Please someone can help me ?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Try `loadtxt()` with the argument `encoding='utf-8'`.

Comment: Does not look like your file is really as you present in your 3 lines. Instead, it looks like you have binary format.

Comment: what is OS, I am a very very very beginner in python I am doing this for my physics class I don't know that much about coding and python in general

Comment: yes deponovo my file is as you described it , someone edited it

Comment: If your file has been modified, you simply need to get back the original file. Can't expect anything to work until then.

Comment: OS = Operating System. Windows, Mac, Linx etc.